# Several text files to csv with filename

Tags: python, csv, filenames, txt

I have several text files in a folder and I would like to transpose them to csv. In each line, I would like to have in a column the name of my file, and in another column the content, for example:

file1.txt, All the text included in this file

file2.txt, More text here

...

I am using the following code:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
files=os.listdir("where the text files are saved")
content=[]
for file in files: 
    with open(file, 'r', newline='') as source_file: 
        for line in csv.reader(source_file): 
            content.append(line[0]) 
with open('output.csv', 'w') as target_file: 
    for line in content: 
        target_file.write(out_filename + "," + line + '\n')
```

However, with this code I am only able to obtain in my csv the content of the text files. Could anyone explain how can I add the filename in a column?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
filelocation = "FILELOCATION"
files= [k for k in next(os.walk(f"{filelocation}"))][2]
filenames = []
content=[]
for file in files:
    with open(f"{filelocation}\\{file}", 'r', newline='') as source_file:
        filenames.append(file)
        lines = source_file.read()
        content.append(lines)

data = {'Filename':filenames,
        'Content':content}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)

df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: You might prefer [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) over `f"{filelocation}\\{file}"`

Comment: Thank you. The code permits me to obtain one column with the filename and another with the content, as I wanted. However my text is in french, so for some reason words like "élections" are replaced by "Ã©lections" or "françois" by "franÃ§ois". Is there a way to avoid this? This did not happen with the previous code.

Comment: Not sure about the language. But you can reusue and merge the code you used if that works. Just append your line[0] to a list. And after going through each line at the end of that loop for that file, append that list to content

Comment: As I said I'm not sure about the language, it could be the pandas implementation, in which case either way of reading the file wouldn't work. Then it would be a matter of writing to csv differently

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It seems to me that the problem is in the pandas. Maybe if I use: with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file, I do not obtain these errors. But I do not know how to finish this code.

Comment: in the code provided, does it alter the characters when you do print(df)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only alters the characters in the csv file

Comment: try df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv', index = False, encoding="utf-8")

Comment: also if you are opening in excel, have a look and see what it looks like in a text editor?